# How to get data from 4 tables in 1 sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have the following database schema:

```
table courses:
id
tutor_id
title



table course_categories:
    id
    category_id
    course_id

table categories:
    id
    name

table tutors:
    id
    name

table subscribers:
    id
    course_id
    user_id
```

I need to make 1 sql to get a course with all it's categories, and the tutor for that course and the number of subscribers for that course. Can this be done in 1 query? Should this be done using stored procedures?

Comment: No, it should not be done with stored procedures. Those are used for updating data, not selecting it.

Comment: @troelskn are you serious? yes you can do it with a single query, using JOINs (you'll need more than one). show us your attempts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this query you get what you want:

```
select co.title as course,
       ca.name as category,
       t.name as tutor,
       count(s.*) as total_subscribers
from courses co
inner join course_categories cc on c.id = cc.course_id
inner join categories ca on cc.category_id = ca.id
inner join tutors t on co.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
left join subscribers s on co.id = s.course_id
where co.title = 'Cat1'
group by co.title, ca.name, t.name
```

I used `left join` on `subscribers` because there might be no one for a given `course`. I'm assuming that all the other tables have data on it for every `course`, `categorie` and `tutor`. If not, you can user `left join` as well but then you'll have data with null.

Comment: thank you, how can I filter the data to get something like Course - Cat1, Cat2, ... now I get 2 rows like Course-Cat1 and Course-Cat2

Comment: @VariuSergiu I've edit my answer. just add a `where clause`. I'm assuming Cat1 is the title of a course.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. You need to look up `select` and the use of `join`. See  [select](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) and [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to help complete the assignment

Answer (score 0):

select cou.title, cat.name, tu.name, count(sub.user_id) from courses cou, course_categories cca, categories cat, tutors tu, subscribers sub where cou.id = cca.id and cat.id = tu.id and tu.id = sub.id group by cou.title, tu.name;

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.